# How could I extract text and Images from DOCX using tika version 2.4.1?

Tags: extract, apache-tika

When using tika version 1.27, I use AutoDetector and AutoParser to extract text and images from DOCX. But in tika version 2.4.1, AutoDetector detects the format of DOCX file is "application/zip", and the parser it used is PackageParser. How could I correctly extract text and images from DOCX?

Comment: Loads of Apache Tika unit tests showing this working just fine... How are you calling Apache Tika, and how did you go about adding all the Parsers and their Dependencies to your project?

Comment: I agree with @Gagravarr.  Have you added tika-parsers-standard-package to your class path?